# .sh file CLI bash error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This error is happening on 16.04 when I try to run a sh script for the qb64 instaler.

```
james@ubuntu:~/qb64$ ./setup_lnx.sh 
bash: ./setup_lnx.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
james@ubuntu:~/qb64$
```

Comment: You need to remove windows line endings from the file... if it is compatible with Linux at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file has **DOS/Windows style line endings (CR LF)**, but on Unix-like systems only the **LF** control character is used as line break.

The additional [**CR** control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is shown encoded as `^M` in your output. You can also see it when you run `cat -A setup_lnx.sh`.

To convert the line endings from DOS/Windows style to Unix style, there's a tool called `dos2unix`. You install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then you can simply convert files' line endings in both ways using

```
dos2unix FILENAME
unix2dos FILENAME
```

In your case, simply run this command below and the script file will be converted in-place:

```
dos2unix setup_lnx.sh
```

After that Bash should be able to interpret the file correctly.